# Pandas, str.extract multiple expression error - ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I am using pandas str.extract method and have used multiple regular expressions in the pattern via '|'. str.extract does not like more than one regular expression it seems. How can I use 'or' with extract?

Here is an extract of the data:-

```
Window
13/01/2020 - AM
10/01/2020
06/01/2020 -\r10/01/2020
08/01/2020 - AM
02/12/2019 -\r17/01/2020
20/01/2020 -\r21/01/2020
09/01/2020 - AM
```

Here is the code:-

```
part_b = df.loc[df['Release_Date'].str.contains("Part B")]

regex_string = '(^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\-)\\r(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})|(^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})|[A]:\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s\w{2}\\r\w{4}\s[B]:\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})'

df['Part_b_window'] = part_b['Window'].str.extract(regex_string)
```

The error:-

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1
```

Please note the regular expressions are working fine when tested [here](https://regex101.com/).

Now in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) it says "*A pattern with two groups will return a DataFrame with two columns. Non-matches will be NaN.*" But I want to keep the output of all five in one column as I am just extracting good data from the mess that is my dataset. How would I be able to do this please?

Comment: What does 'Pat' mean? (1st sentence).

Comment: Sorry, ‘regular expression pattern’.

Comment: So I have found this solution, but it seems a little long-winded. The solution is to output to multiple columns and then merge back using the _where_ method. [link](https://python-forum.io/Thread-pandas-str-extract-multiple-regex-groups-with-OR)

Answer (score 1):

So I have this working now. I misunderstood the problem a little but printing this variable I could see the output from str.extract was working and it was when I tried to assign to the df that there was the mismatch.

I tweaked this code to assign to a variable t.

```
t = df['Release_Date'].str.extract('(?:.*\:\s)(.*)\\r|(^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})|(^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\*)|\\r(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})') 
print(t)
```

Here is the output from t.

[image]

This is the code I used to solve the problem.

```
df['Part_b_window'] = t[0].fillna(t[1]).fillna(t[2]).fillna(t[3]).fillna(t[4]).fillna('Miscellaneous')
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the extract method with the regex below:

```
.str.extract(r'(_(\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2})_metre_)')
```

Then I just set it up to do not capture groups:

```
.str.extract(r'(_(?:\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2})_metre_)')
```

So this solved the problem to me. If it works for you as a short winded solution, please vote!